# Start up issues after fresh install

Tags: system-installation, graphics, gpu-driver

I have a HP Pavilion dv7-4263cl with the following specs

Memory Module Specifications
Total Memory Size   8GB

Processor Specifications
Processor Brand AMD
Processor Class Phenom II
Processor Type  Triple-Core
Processor Speed 2.0GHz
Processor Number    P860

Hard Disk Drive Specifications
Capacity    640GB
Drive Types Hard Drive
Hard Drive Speed    5400 RPM

Graphics Specifications
GPU/VPU ATI Mobility Radeon HD 6370 s
Video Memory    itchable graphics

Optical Drive Specifications
Optical Drive   DVD Super Multi Dual Layer Burner

Communications
Communications Description  Integrated LAN
    Integrated Wireless LAN
Interface Type  802.11b/g/n Wireless Networking
    Integrated 10/100/1000 Gigabit Ethernet LAN

The issue is I use my HDMI port quite often but on the generic driver the port does not work. I have two proprietary AMD drivers but if I load either one it wont fully load the computer after restart. I enter my log in credentials I get the purple desktop background and an error System program problem detected do you want to report the problem now? regardless if I hit report problem or I hit cancel it just sends me to a blank purple desktop. This seems to only happen when I load the proprietary drivers, it hasn't happened on the generic graphics driver. I have uninstalled about 5 times as this seems to be the only way to return the driver back to the generic. Im really new to Ubuntu can anyone help?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the proprietary AMD drivers? Update your post with this infomation.

Comment: What would you like to know about the drivers and how would I find this information as I updated the post with more details. After the start up I just get a blank purple desktop and can not do anything.

Comment: I have the same machine, and found that the oibaf drivers work pretty well:  I get the hardware acceleration that I want/need for Ubuntu, but not the unstability of the xoerg-edgers.  The AMD drivers do not work with the DV7 for some reason.  I have not tried the HDMI output though.  The oibaf drivers can be found at https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers